# Select minimum value with group by in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, select

My Database scheme,

```
CREATE TABLE `result` (
`ID` bigint(21) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`datetime` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
`recordnum` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`recordtype` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`minvalue` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`maxvalue` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`data1` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`data2` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`area` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
UNIQUE KEY `res` (`datetime`,`recordnum`,`area`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=7 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Sample of data

> ```
> INSERT INTO `result` VALUES ('1', '2013-03-26 12:03:31', '2', '1', '5', '10', '100', '200','Zone1');
>
> INSERT INTO `result` VALUES ('2', '2013-03-26 12:03:31', '2', '1', '2', '7', '20', '20','Zone2');
>
> INSERT INTO `result` VALUES ('3', '2013-03-26 12:03:31', '5', '2', '1', '2', '8', '15','Zone2');
>
> INSERT INTO `result` VALUES ('4', '2013-03-26 12:00:31', '2', '1', '2', '7', '100', '200','Zone1');
>
> INSERT INTO `result` VALUES ('5', '2013-03-26 12:00:31', '2', '1', '3', '9', '100', '200','Zone2');
>
> INSERT INTO `result` VALUES ('6', '2013-03-26 12:00:31', '5', '2', '7', '2', '4', '10', 'Zone2');
>
> INSERT INTO `result` VALUES ('7', '2013-03-25 12:03:31', '2', '1', '5', '10', '100', '200','Zone1');
>
> INSERT INTO `result` VALUES ('8', '2013-03-25 12:03:31', '2', '1', '2', '7', '20', '20','Zone2');
>
> INSERT INTO `result` VALUES ('9', '2013-03-25 12:03:31', '5', '2', '1', '2', '8', '15','Zone2');
>
> INSERT INTO `result` VALUES ('10', '2013-03-25 12:00:31', '2', '1', '2', '7', '100', '200','Zone1');
>
> INSERT INTO `result` VALUES ('11', '2013-03-25 12:00:31', '2', '1', '3', '9', '100', '200','Zone2');
>
> INSERT INTO `result` VALUES ('12', '2013-03-25 12:00:31', '5', '2', '7', '2', '4', '10','Zone2');
>
>
> INSERT INTO `result` VALUES ('13', '2013-03-25 11:03:31', '2', '1', '3', '10', '100','200', 'Zone1');
>
> INSERT INTO `result` VALUES ('14', '2013-03-25 11:03:31', '2', '1', '8', '7', '20', '20','Zone2');
>
> INSERT INTO `result` VALUES ('15', '2013-03-25 11:03:31', '5', '2', '2', '2', '8', '15','Zone2');
>
> INSERT INTO `result` VALUES ('16', '2013-03-25 11:00:31', '2', '1', '1', '7', '100', '200','Zone1');
>
> INSERT INTO `result` VALUES ('17', '2013-03-25 11:00:31', '2', '1', '9', '9', '100', '200','Zone2');
>
> INSERT INTO `result` VALUES ('18', '2013-03-25 11:00:31', '5', '2', '12', '2', '4', '10','Zone2');
> ```

What I want is query every value when minvalue is minimum for each **recordnum** and **area** and also **date**

```
  +----+---------------------+-----------+-------+----------+----------+-------+-------+------------+
    | ID | datetime            | recordnum | area  |minvalue  | maxvalue | data1 | data2 | recordtype |
    +----+---------------------+-----------+-------+----------+----------+-------+-------+------------+
    |  2 | 2013-03-26 12:03:31 |         2 | Zone2 |        2 |        7 |    20 |    20 |          1 |
    |  3 | 2013-03-26 12:03:31 |         5 | Zone2 |        1 |        2 |     8 |    15 |          2 |
    |  4 | 2013-03-26 12:00:31 |         2 | Zone1 |        2 |        7 |   100 |   200 |          1 |
    |  8 | 2013-03-25 12:03:31 |         2 | Zone2 |        2 |        7 |    20 |    20 |          1 |
    |  9 | 2013-03-25 12:03:31 |         5 | Zone2 |        1 |        2 |     8 |    15 |          2 |
    | 16 | 2013-03-25 11:00:31 |         2 | Zone1 |        1 |        7 |   100 |   200 |          1 |
    +----+---------------------+-----------+-------+----------+----------+-------+-------+------------+
```

This query below gave good result but still has duplicate record displayed, please help

```
SELECT  a.*
FROM    result a
        JOIN
        (
            SELECT  datetime as mindatetime,DATE(datetime) dateOnly,area, recordNum, MIN(minvalue) min_val
            FROM    result
            GROUP   BY dateOnly,area, recordNum
        ) b  ON a.area = b.area AND
                a.recordNUM = b.recordNum AND
                a.minvalue = b.min_val ;
+----+---------------------+-----------+------------+----------+----------+-------+-------+-------+
| ID | datetime            | recordnum | recordtype | minvalue | maxvalue | data1 | data2 | area  |
+----+---------------------+-----------+------------+----------+----------+-------+-------+-------+
|  2 | 2013-03-26 12:03:31 |         2 |          1 |        2 |        7 |    20 |    20 | Zone2 |
|  2 | 2013-03-26 12:03:31 |         2 |          1 |        2 |        7 |    20 |    20 | Zone2 |
|  3 | 2013-03-26 12:03:31 |         5 |          2 |        1 |        2 |     8 |    15 | Zone2 |
|  3 | 2013-03-26 12:03:31 |         5 |          2 |        1 |        2 |     8 |    15 | Zone2 |
|  4 | 2013-03-26 12:00:31 |         2 |          1 |        2 |        7 |   100 |   200 | Zone1 |
|  8 | 2013-03-25 12:03:31 |         2 |          1 |        2 |        7 |    20 |    20 | Zone2 |
|  8 | 2013-03-25 12:03:31 |         2 |          1 |        2 |        7 |    20 |    20 | Zone2 |
|  9 | 2013-03-25 12:03:31 |         5 |          2 |        1 |        2 |     8 |    15 | Zone2 |
|  9 | 2013-03-25 12:03:31 |         5 |          2 |        1 |        2 |     8 |    15 | Zone2 |
| 10 | 2013-03-25 12:00:31 |         2 |          1 |        2 |        7 |   100 |   200 | Zone1 |
| 16 | 2013-03-25 11:00:31 |         2 |          1 |        1 |        7 |   100 |   200 | Zone1 |
+----+---------------------+-----------+------------+----------+----------+-------+-------+-------+
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get top n records for each group of grouped results](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12113699/get-top-n-records-for-each-group-of-grouped-results)

Answer (score 10):

There are many variations on how to solve this problem. One is by using a separate subquery which gets the minimum `minvalue` for every `area and recordNum`. The result of the subquery is then joined back on the original table so you can get all the columns within the row.

```
SELECT  a.*
FROM    result a
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT  area, recordNum, MIN(minvalue) min_val
            FROM    result
            GROUP   BY area, recordNum
        ) b  ON a.area = b.area AND
                a.recordNUM = b.recordNum AND
                a.minvalue = b.min_val
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8270c/2)

OUTPUT

```
╔════╦══════════════════════════════╦═══════════╦════════════╦══════════╦══════════╦═══════╦═══════╦═══════╗
║ ID ║           DATETIME           ║ RECORDNUM ║ RECORDTYPE ║ MINVALUE ║ MAXVALUE ║ DATA1 ║ DATA2 ║ AREA  ║
╠════╬══════════════════════════════╬═══════════╬════════════╬══════════╬══════════╬═══════╬═══════╬═══════╣
║  2 ║ March, 26 2013 12:03:31+0000 ║         2 ║          1 ║        2 ║        7 ║    20 ║    20 ║ Zone2 ║
║  3 ║ March, 26 2013 12:03:31+0000 ║         5 ║          2 ║        1 ║        2 ║     8 ║    15 ║ Zone2 ║
║  4 ║ March, 26 2013 12:00:31+0000 ║         2 ║          1 ║        2 ║        7 ║   100 ║   200 ║ Zone1 ║
╚════╩══════════════════════════════╩═══════════╩════════════╩══════════╩══════════╩═══════╩═══════╩═══════╝
```

Comment: Thanks, query work perfectly, I have another  question how to add  group base on day , i added `group by DATE_FORMAT(DATETIME,'%Y-%m-%d')` so I want MINVALUE for one day but it's not working, thanks in adv.

Comment: what is lacking on the result here? do you want to format the date and why do you need to add it on group by clause??

Comment: No, the query result is working, I want to know how to get the minimum value for daily basis.

Comment: I just update the sample of data on the top Question also the expected result, only 1  unique record base on combination date , recordnum and area when MINVALUE  record is minimum.

Comment: Now i got the result but still need to remove duplicate record, any suggestion?

Comment: can i see those records? even with print screen?

Comment: I put  the sample data and query  on the top question,